# Isn't AWS kinessis starting position of LATEST contrary to the concept of FIFO?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis

AWS documentation at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesis/latest/APIReference/API_StartingPosition.html explains the starting position parameter. This is the explanation of the LATEST option:

Start streaming just after the most recent record in the shard, so that you always read the most recent data in the shard.

I was under the impression that a kinesis stream is FIFO per shard - see [AWS Kinesis Stream as FIFO queue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42686276/aws-kinesis-stream-as-fifo-queue).
More accurately, each shard can only have one processor at a given moment (per application). So this seems natuarally like FIFO if starting position is set to TRIM_HORIZON.
Does configuring starting position to LATEST mean that messages will not necessarily be processed in the order in which they arrive?

Comment: TRIM_HORIZON reads records that are currently in the stream, LATEST doesn't. With either, you read the shard in the order events arrived, which is FIFO.

Answer (score 0):

> I was under the impression that a kinesis stream is FIFO per shard

This is not correct, Kinesis streams provide ordering per shard, but that does not mean its delivery is FIFO, as that logic is up to the consumer and not the stream itself.

Setting the iterator to `LATEST` would give the impression of FIFO per shard, as you are always reading from the latest entry of the stream. However, using `TRIM_HORIZON` would mean you read from the oldest entry of the stream and work your way towards the latest, which is the opposite of FIFO.

Comment: TRIM_HORIZON does _not_ mean that you read from the tail of the stream. It means that you read from the head of the stream including all records that are currently stored in the stream.

Comment: Why would setting the iterator to LASTEST give the impression of FIFO? Suppose 2 events are inserted into the stream: ev1 and ev2. The consumer will then start to read from the stream and if LATEST is set it should read ev2 first which breaks FIFO. Also, what happens if processing of a message fails and is retried? For example, if the consumer starts with ev1, then ev2 comes in, then ev1 fails. So now the consumer needs to either retry ev1 again or process ev2. If LATEST is confugured I would assume that the consumer should read ev2 which again breaks FIFO.